# AngularJS Module 'ngCookies' is not available MEAN stack

Tags: angularjs, cookies, mean-stack

I have looked through a few similar questions but most of them relate to having Angular loaded AFTER angular-cookies, in my case this isn't true, I have been following a tutorial on creating an AngularCMS using the MEAN stack (check site [Building a CMS in the MEAN stack](https://masteringmean.com/lessons/435-Building-a-CMS-on-the-MEAN-Stack)).

I have just completed the section that includes cookies for session authentication at an admin level. The issue I have is as the title states, I hit an error loading the login page saying that ngCookies is not available. I have installed angular-cookies via bower and it asked me to include angular 1.5.0 as it is a dependency.

I have tried calling the angular script on my index.html but I get an additional error saying I am trying to load Angular twice.

My relating code is as follows:

**app.js**

```
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'myApp.filters',
  'myApp.services',
  'myApp.directives',
  'myApp.controllers',
  'ngCookies'
]).
```

**index.html**

```
    <script src="js/filters.js"></script>
    <script src="js/directives.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
</body>
```

Please Help

Comment: it's probably not the reason for the error but you should be putting your filters and directives etc after loading angular.

Comment: @mentat yea, sorry, that is a double up of Angular there, need to edit post and remove, thanks

EDIT: updated to show current working set

Comment: by the way, you can choose angular-cookies version to match your angular (in bower). I suppose you already had angular before ngCookies.

Comment: yea, I'm trying to find what version of angular I have i used the express-generator module to start me off, I'll see if its mentioned somewhere in my logs

Comment: just look at the bower directory, angular.js file starts with version text. You might be using the online version though.. check your index.html to see where it's loaded from..

Comment: I had installed the wrong version, I have specified version download and it works fine now, thanks for hinting the right places to look.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had installed the wrong version of angular-cookies, noob note: Always check your versions!!